# The selected field in the subquery and the left operand field in the where expression in the outer query

Tags: soql

I am trying to execute this SOQL:

```
productIdsThatExist = [SELECT id 
                      FROM Product2 
                      WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
                                   FROM Cross_sell__c 
                                   WHERE (Accountforproduct__c =: acc.id) 
                                   AND (Discussion_status__c!=null)
                                   )];
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Compile Error: The selected field 'id' in the subquery and the left operand field in the where expression in the outer query 'id' should point to the same object type at line 64 column 30
```

My data model is:

```
Accounts > MD > Cross_sell__c < Lookup < Products
```

Which seems to be exactly the same as in [Salesforce's deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries.](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example from [Salesforce's deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) is this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Position_c WHERE Id NOT IN
(SELECT Position__c FROM Job_Application__c)
```

Note that the sub-query is selecting the id (`Position__c`) to the Position record. You will need to do the same thing. You should be selecting the field that has the Id to `Cross_sell__c`. You are currently are comparing a `Product2` Id to a `Cross_sell__c` Id. You SOQL should be something like this:

```
productIdsThatExist = [SELECT id 
                      FROM Product2 
                      WHERE Cross_sell__c IN (SELECT id 
                                   FROM Cross_sell__c 
                                   WHERE (Accountforproduct__c =: acc.id) 
                                   AND (Discussion_status__c!=null)
                                   )];
```

Comment: Ahhh. Got it. Seems so obvious now. I think their example wasn't very good! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In your outer `WHERE` clause put the correct reference API name for `Cross_sell__c`

```
productIdsThatExist = [SELECT id 
                          FROM Product2 
                          WHERE Cross_sell__c IN (SELECT id 
                                       FROM Cross_sell__c 
                                       WHERE (Accountforproduct__c =: acc.id) 
                                       AND (Discussion_status__c!=null)
                                       )];
```

Comment: could you able to resolve the issue? if you can't find the Lookup API Name, check it in the WSDL https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gx2mAAA